# Why does Artifactory not list/cache NuGet Packages from remote NuGet Gallery repo?

Tags: nuget, artifactory, nugetgallery

I'm looking to migrate from an existing private NuGet Gallery repo. We have Artifactory (v6.10.1 , will be upgrading soon) with a nuget virtual, nuget-local, and nuget-remote-cache repo.

I have configured the Artifactory remote repo to point to the NuGet Gallery server and as you can see from the screenshot below, it passes the connection test. However, when I try to `nuget list` from the remote repo, I get no packages returned. If I try the same call directly against the NuGet Gallery, I get lots of packages returned. My account has the "anything" permission in artifactory (Effective permissions shows all 4 checks) and no authentication is required to retrieve from either NuGet Gallery or the artifactory repo but I've set up my un/pw and apikey all the same. If I try to browse Packages, NuGet isn't even available. In Artifacts, the only thing that shows up is the package.json from the local repo. What is going on here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I had enabled "Global Offline mode" so Artifactory was refusing to even attempt to access the Remote repository. This was evident by the complete lack of log entries in the request.log. Disabling the setting allowed the list to list packages.

I still did not see any packages in the cache but after running `nuget install <package>`, it appeared in the cache. Apparently the caching only occurs on a pull of a package and does not function as a full replica of the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

Remote repositories in Artifactory serves as a caching proxy that the URL of the repository points to. To have the control over the storage of your hardware, the artifacts are being cached by demand of the users therefore it’s not being synced with the remote URL.

With this said, if the remote repository is pointing to other Artifactory repository you can set the pull replication feature of Artifactory to retrieve the artifacts from the remote Artifactory server and populate the remote repository cache and in this way to synchronize the repositories.